# Visual Studio 2015 Windows Phone Emulator not deploying

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, hyper-v, windows-phone-8-emulator

Guys please help me ...

I tried every steps that are avail. in stack overflow but every time it  creates new error & now am stuck at here !! look[image]

At back in Hyper-V manager my windows is loaded already !! but in emulator it's stuck . &  it gives an error

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Lolz !! After 3 Days & 18 hours it finally Works ... here is the solution of above problem that works for me

[image]

- Just right Click on the your Virtual Machine for both Windows 10 & 8.1 & Go to Settings

Their you will find Windows Phone Emulator Internal Switch & Select the optn. of Enable Virtual LAN Identification

[image]

& then it Should work for Both Windows Phone 8.1 & 10 . :) !! Work For Me at least !! Here Look -->

[image]