# Visual Studio 2015 Windows Phone Emulator not deploying 6

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2015, emulation

I have been facing the same issue as asked in this other post

[Visual Studio 2015 Windows Phone Emulator not deploying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34548204/visual-studio-2015-windows-phone-emulator-not-deploying)

but the solution worked here is not working for me.

Windows 10 pro upgraded from home version

Visual Studio 2015

Apache Cordova "Sample" app.

In Emulator it is showing as "Starting

in the behind "Hyper-V" "Summary" it is visible but if double click the the Hyper-V "instance" it is not visible there but only in "Summary"

What am I missing here?

For the developer sake and investment, MS must make sure that the solutions are tested everywhere before releasing them.

This link will direct you to print screen of the error. https://prnt.sc/cykrgg

in the VS output we get the following last message.

My OS is 64 bit.

2>The build configuration was changed to x86 for x86-based emulator deployment.

could this be impact of 64 to 86 bit version difference or anything else?

I have Norton antivirus

I am getting

Hyper-v administrator pop up every time I try to run the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This case is resolved by Microsoft Support Team over a Ticket and Rohit, support engg from MS did really helped me a lot.

The reason why it was not coming up.....

My machine has a AdWareAntiVirus from Lavasoft by Name WebCompanion that was not allowing it work.

I removed it then it started working.

if any body have any problem with VS 2015 Emulator definitely focus on the Antivirus and include the Emulator XDE into exception list and also include in Firewall.

Thanks,

Ekambar